# version control on individual files

Tags: version-control

I have been researching how to move from VSS but am running into an issue.  We MUST be able to have versioning on individual files and we also MUST be able to do keyword substitution.

TLDNR:
Are there are versioning control systems out there that support both keyword substitution AND individual file versioning?  I am open to any type of suggestion that results in these two conditions being met. If you need to know why we need these things you can continue to read but my question remains.

---

Our files are small html files.  They are totally unrelated to each other.  No branching or anything. We have thousands of them.  I can go into the details of what they are used for if someone asks but the software we use them with, as well as our clients, rely on each and every file having it's own revision number.  VSS does keyword substitution on a revision meta tag in the file each time it is checked in to VSS.  That revision number is read by our software that uses the html file, and is reported to both clients and other people in the company that need to see it.

Every discussion I see on the internet that starts off asking for individual file revisioning ends up with everyone just saying "People don't do that anymore, just get used to it."  That answer is unacceptable. :) 
Our project is very much NOT like the typical coding project.

So!!  I have been playing around with Subversion because I found out it does keyword substution, and I got that to work just fine, however, I discovered that all files get a new revision number each time one of them is edited and committed.

I have thought that maybe each file could be placed in it's own project, but as I mentioned before, we have many files, approaching 19k right now, and that method seemed like it would be a huge pain.

We would just stick with VSS but the database is getting large enough now that VSS is struggling with it.

Answer (score 0):

RCS and CVS use per-file version-numbering and support keyword substition/expansion.

Comment: Thank you.  So, RCS is the original system, and CVS was an update to that?  I noticed that CVS hasnt had an update in many years.  I had of course hoped for some newer software, but if this is the only real option we have then that's fine, its still many years newer than VSS. :D

Comment: It's about 6 years ago that I worked with http://www.mkssoftware.com/. I remember under the hood they were using RCS. I have no idea about their current products though. You also might want to look at http://www.perforce.com/.